# Can I add a line to the reflog?

Tags: git, git-reflog

I am in the middle of rebase hell due to a botched `git commit --fixup`. I think I've identified the source and I'm in a better place than I started. However, if I look at the git reflog, this sequence of 'rebase -i' lines looks just like my previous botched attempts.

Can I add my own line to the reflog? Say something that would look like:

```
$ git reflog mark '== we are not worse off than we started here =='
$ git reflog -3
cb6536f HEAD@{0}: mark: == we are not worse off than we started here ==
cb6536f HEAD@{1}: rebase -i (finish): fixup! foo: baz the widgets
9db07de HEAD@{1}: rebase -i (pick): fixup! baz: implement widget bazzing
```

Comment: The closest think I can think of is `git commit --fixup HEAD --allow-empty`, though that creates an actual commit that would go away on its own harmlessly on the next `git rebase -i --autosquash`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add a new reflog entry at any time using the same command git uses to add new reflog entries, namely [`git update-ref`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-ref.html).  This is a "plumbing" (script-oriented) command so it is not very user friendly, and you might want to add your own little wrapper script or alias.

Examples:

```
git update-ref -m 'mark: whatever' HEAD HEAD
git update-ref -m 'mark: another thing' refs/heads/branch branch
git update-ref -m 'mark: third thing' refs/heads/branch refs/heads/branch
hash=$(git rev-parse refs/heads/branch) && \
   git update-ref -m 'mark: 4' refs/heads/branch $hash
```

Note that the `<ref>` (the first non-option argument) must be fully spelled out.  The `<newvalue>` can be anything that resolves to a valid SHA-1, which is why the middle command of the three examples can work, but for safety it is probably best to use the third form (repeat the `<ref>` exactly) or use an actual SHA-1 hash (fourth form), letting `git rev-parse` verify that this is in fact a valid branch name.

(When using `HEAD` you can skip validation since git cannot function at all if `HEAD` is not a valid name.)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [2020 thread](https://public-inbox.org/git/20200226023909.GC7911@camp.crustytoothpaste.net/T/#u):

> There is the [option `core.logAllRefUpdates`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corelogAllRefUpdates), which has the value "`always`"
>   in more modern versions of Git.
>   The documentation says:
>
> If the option is set to `always`, then a missing reflog is automatically created for any ref under refs/.
>
> Now, that assumes that you want reflogs for all your refs, but there's really not much downside to having a reflog and not using it.

Jeff Kings adds:

> The current rule is actually to append to any reflog that already exists, or to consult `core.logAllRefUpdates` when deciding whether to create one that doesn't exist. So I think setting a one-shot config variable like:
>
> ```
> git -c core.logAllRefUpdates=always update-ref refs/foo/bar ...
> ```
>
> would create the reflog, and then any subsequent updates (even without that config set) would append to it.
>
> You can also do this:
>
> ```
> mkdir -p .git/logs/refs/foo/
> touch .git/logs/refs/foo/bar
> git update-ref refs/foo/bar ...
> ```
>
> but I wouldn't recommend it.
>   When we eventually move to supporting other ref backend formats, they won't necessarily store the logs in the same way.